# Upload image as virtual swatch option in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I ran into a problem. When I upload a file (image) as visual swatch attribute in Magento 2.2.2, nothing happens I see an empty field (I attached a screenshot)

[image]

Access log show a `POST` request with response code 200, and I checked the directory `pub/media/attribute/swatch/swatch_image/30x20/0/1` the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to need change of core file other wise override to it**

Path : vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Adminhtml/Attribute/Edit/OptionsVisual.php

```
public function getJsonConfig()
     * Parse swatch labels for template
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @param null $swatchStoreValue  //Remove
     * @return string                //Remove
     * @param null|array $swatchStoreValue  //Add
     * @return null|array                   //Add
     */
    protected function reformatSwatchLabels($swatchStoreValue = null)
    {
        if ($swatchStoreValue === null) {
            return;
        }
        $newSwatch = '';  // Remove
        $newSwatch = [];  //Add
        foreach ($swatchStoreValue as $key => $value) {
            if ($value[0] == '#') {
                $newSwatch[$key] = 'background: '.$value;
```